# Woocommerce custom style for specific product category?

Tags: woocommerce

Is there an easy way to add a custom style to a specific products in Woocommerce? For example, I want all products with a category of 'Category1' to have a blue page background color, and all products with a category of 'Category2' to have a white page background color.

Unfortunately, I am mostly clueless when it comes to PHP. Can you explain the solution to me like I'm a 5th grader?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to ad a function to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```php
// add taxonomy term to body_class
function woo_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class( $classes ){
  if( is_singular( 'product' ) )
  {
    $custom_terms = get_the_terms(0, 'product_cat');
    if ($custom_terms) {
      foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
        $classes[] = 'product_cat_' . $custom_term->slug;
      }
    }
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'woo_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class' );
```

This function is [cribbed from here.](https://gist.github.com/thegdshop/3197540)
This function will add the product category slug as a class name to the `<body>` element, which will allow you to target the styles specifically for that page.

Comment: Is there anything more to do then to add this to functions.php? Because it is not working for me, no additional classes added to the body tag.