# How do I change the css of my page based on woocommerce parent product category?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the css of my page based on the selected woocommerce parent product category. I want to change the colour scheme of my navbar and footer based on these categories. I have already created the style sheets to achieve this and if I change the css path in developer options on my browser it works.

I have tried editing the taxonomy-product_cat.php file and I am able to successfully navigate to a different page using the following code:

```
// Get current category slug
global $wp_query;
$cat_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'];

// Call template conditionally
if($cat_slug == 'sport-bikes') {
    wc_get_template( 'archive-land.php' );
} else  {
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );   
}
```

The two issues I've encountered here are:

1) This only works for the specific sub-category - If I use the parent category "land" it does not work.

2) I'm unable to edit the css from whatever template I use. In this instance I created the "archive-land.php" template.

I have also tried adding the following to my functions.php file:

```
// add taxonomy term to body_class
function woo_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class( $classes ){
  if( is_singular( 'product' ) )
  {
    $custom_terms = get_the_terms(0, 'product_cat');
    if ($custom_terms) {
      foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
        $classes[] = 'product_cat_' . $custom_term->slug;
      }
    }
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'woo_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class' );
```

Based on the following solution on this link:
[Woocommerce custom style for specific product category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015133/woocommerce-custom-style-for-specific-product-category)

The issues encountered here are:

1) The body class remains as " customize-support"

2) My css files are specific to changing the colour of the headers and footers

Basically I just want to change the colour scheme of my headers and footers based on the parent product category.

**Edit:**

Partially solved - I've created a separate "archive-land.php" and "archive-marine.php" and added the following code to the top of each file calling the css files I need:

```
<?php
function c3land_theme_styles(){   
    wp_enqueue_style( 'hoverland', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/hoverland.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'land', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/land.css' );            
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','c3land_theme_styles' );
?>
```

This takes care of switching the css but I still need to have them changed on the parent category rather than the sub-categories here is my updated code on taxonomy-product_cat.php file:

```
// Get current category slug
global $wp_query;
$cat_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'];

// Call template conditionally
if($cat_slug == 'sport-bikes') {
    wc_get_template( 'archive-land.php' );
} 
if($cat_slug == 'outboard-motors') {
    wc_get_template( 'archive-marine.php' );
} 
else  {
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );   
}
```

1) Are there any potential issues in my initial proposed solution or is there a more elegant / proper way of achieving this ?

2) How to I call my "archive-land.php or archive-marine.php" by the parent category ?

Comment: How about having color option in backend of parent category? That might solve problem easily rather custom coding so much i think.

Comment: I'm fairly new to WP - I'm still trying to research this angle but can you advise how I would start to go about this ?

Comment: Yes, you can use Advanced Custom Field plugin and add meta box in parent categories. If you find difficulties you can contact me from my link on my profile. :)